# Uncaught Action failed: aura:iteration$controller$itemsChange [Cannot read property 'O' of undefined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My lightning component is intermittently getting this error message in my QA sandbox. what is property O? I have used dualListbox, when the first value is selected, there is no issue, when the second one selected, the error starts happening. Sometimes happened sometimes didn't.

[image]

----- Aura Component ---

```
<aura:component controller="RetrieveProjectNotesController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="lstProject" type="RetrieveProjectNotesController.ProjectWrapper[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="mapNotes" type="object"/>
    <!--aura:attribute name="lstProjectEpic" type ="Project_Epic__c[]"/-->
    <aura:attribute name="userProfile" type="String"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

 
      <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="List" default="[]"/>

 
    <lightning:dualListbox name="multipleOptions"  
                           label="Project Departments" 
                           sourceLabel="Available" 
                           selectedLabel="Selected" 
                           options="{!v.options}" 
                           value="{!v.values}" 
                           onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
                           fieldLevelHelp="Select department(s) to view the list of projects associated with the selected department(s)"
                           size="2"/>
             
   <div class="c-container">
             <aura:Iteration items="{!v.lstProject}" var="item">                
                     <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                         <lightning:layoutitem  padding="around-small" size="12">
             <lightning:card  >
                 <aura:set  attribute="title"  >
                                          
 
                      <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!item.project.Priority_Color__c}" ></aura:unescapedHtml>  
                     <a href="{!'/'+ item.project.Id}" >  
                         {!item.project.SFDC_Project_Name__c}       </a> 
                     
            

                    
                 </aura:set>  
             
                        </lightning:card>
                         </lightning:layoutitem>
                         
                          <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
                 <div class="page-section page-main">
                     <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Description">Epic:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!item.project.Project_Epic__r.Name}</p>
                         </dd>
                         <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Description">Description:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!item.project.SFDC_Status_Description__c}</p>
                         </dd>
                         
                         <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!item.project.SFDC_Project_Status__c}</p>
                         </dd>       
                         
                         <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="StartDate">Start Date:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                <lightning:formattedDateTime  value="{!item.project.SFDC_Project_Start_Date__c}" year="2-digit" month="2-digit" day="2-digit" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit"    ></lightning:formattedDateTime>    
                         </dd>       
                         
                         <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="StartDate">Project Epic:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!item.project.Project_Epic__r.Name}</p>
                         </dd>   
                     </dl>

                     <div class="page-note">
                     <b>Related Registrars</b>  
                      <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(item.accounts))}">
                
               
                <aura:Iteration items="{!item.accounts}" var="acctP" >
                    <li>
                        {!acctP.Account__r.Name}                     </li>                    
                </aura:Iteration>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <p>There are no project notes for this project.</p> 
                </aura:set>
                     </aura:if>
                     
                     </div>
                     <div class="page-note" >   
                <div class="page-header">
                <b>Project Related Notes</b>
                </div>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(item.notes))}">
                
               
                <aura:Iteration items="{!item.notes}" var="noteP" >
                     <c:DisplayNoteItem item="{!noteP}" /> 
                </aura:Iteration>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <p>There are no project notes for this project.</p> 
                </aura:set>
                     </aura:if>

                     </div>
              </div>
                                                 </lightning:layoutItem>
                         <lightning:LayoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
                    <div class="page-section page-main">
                                        <div class="page-header">
                <b>Project Related Tasks</b>
                </div >
                <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(item.tasks))}">
                   <aura:Iteration items="{!item.tasks}" var ="task">
               
                <div class="page-task  ">
               
                       <li>Task Subject:    <a href="{!'/'+ task.task.Id}" >{!task.task.Subject}</a></li>
                    </div>
                       
                   <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                         <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Comment">Comment:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!task.task.Description}</p>
                         </dd>
                       
                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Diposition">Diposition:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p>  {!task.task.Status}</p>
                         </dd>
                        
                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="Priority">Priority:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
 
                           <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!task.task.Task_Priority_Color__c}" ></aura:unescapedHtml>  
                         </dd>         
                        
                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                              <p class="slds-truncate" title="DueDate">Due Date:</p>
                              </dt>
                         <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail slds-tile__meta">
                     <p> <lightning:formattedDateTime  value="{!task.task.ActivityDate}" year="2-digit" month="2-digit" day="2-digit"  hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit"     ></lightning:formattedDateTime></p>
                         </dd>  
                       
                       </dl>
                       
                       
            <div class="page-note  slds-border_bottom"  >   
                <div class="page-header">
                <b>Task Notes</b>
                </div>
                       <aura:iteration items="{!task.notes}" var="noteT">
                            <c:DisplayNoteItem item="{!noteT}"></c:DisplayNoteItem>
                       </aura:iteration>
                 </div>
                     
                   </aura:Iteration>
                       <aura:set attribute="else">
                           <p>There are no tasks associated with this project</p>
                    </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                             </div> 
                             </lightning:LayoutItem>
             </lightning:layout>          
   

    
            </aura:Iteration> 
           </div>  
        

 
</aura:component>
```

---- Controller.js ----

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getProjectAndTasks(component, event, helper);
       // helper.getNotes (component, event, helper);
      // helper.getProjectEpics(component, event, helper);
        
     //  helper.getNewEpicValue (component,event,helper);
        helper.getUserProfile(component, event, helper);
        helper.getDepartments(component, event, helper); 
    },
    
    handleChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        // This will contain an array of the "value" attribute of the selected options
        var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
       // alert("Option selected with value: '" + selectedOptionValue.toString() + "'");
        
        console.log("Option selected with value: '" + selectedOptionValue.toString() + "'"); 
        
        helper.getProjectAndTasks(component, event, helper);
    }

})
```

---- Helper.js ---

```
({
    getProjectAndTasks : function(component, event, helper) {
                var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
       
          var   action = component.get('c.getProjectWithTaskAndNotesByEpic');
             action.setParams({ "Departments" : selectedOptionValue });
  

                action.setCallback(this,function(response)
                           {
                               var state= response.getState();
                               if(state == "SUCCESS")
                               {
                                   console.log('reponse : ' + response.getReturnValue());
                                   var proj = response.getReturnValue();
                                   
                                
                                   
                                   component.set('v.lstProject',response.getReturnValue());
                               }
                           });
                           $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    getDepartments : function  (component, event, helper){
           
                    var action = component.get('c.getDepartments');
                action.setCallback(this,function(response)
                           {
                               var state= response.getState();
                               if(state == "SUCCESS")
                               {
                                    var departments =response.getReturnValue();
                                   console.log('Departments are : ' + departments);                         
                                    var items =[];
                                   for(var d in departments)
                                   {
                                                 var item = {
                "label":  departments[d] ,
                "value":  departments[d]   
            };
                                                   items.push(item);
                                   }
                                   component.set('v.options',items);
                                   
                               }
                           });
                           $A.enqueueAction(action);    
                          
        
    },

    getProjectEpics : function (component, event, helper){
                        var action = component.get('c.getProjectEpics');
                action.setCallback(this,function(response)
                           {
                               var state= response.getState();
                               if(state == "SUCCESS")
                               {
                                  console.log('reponse : ' + response.getReturnValue());
                                   var epic = response.getReturnValue();                                  
                                
                                   
                                   
    component.set('v.lstProjectEpic',response.getReturnValue());
                                   
                               }
                           });
                           $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } ,
    getUserProfile : function (component, event, helper){
                    var action = component.get('c.fetchUserProfile');
                action.setCallback(this,function(response)
                           {
                               var state= response.getState();
                               if(state == "SUCCESS")
                               {
                                   console.log('reponse : ' + response.getReturnValue());                         
                                   
                                   
       component.set('v.userProfile',response.getReturnValue());
                                   
                               }
                           });
                           $A.enqueueAction(action);       
           }
  
})
```

----- apex controller ----

*** Apex class **

```
public with sharing class RetrieveProjectNotesController   
{   

    private static List<ID> myLstLinkedEntityID = new list<Id>();
    private static List<sfdc_project__c> myLstProject = new List<sfdc_project__c> ();
    private static  List<ContentDocumentLink> myContentDocLink= new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    private static List<project_department__c> pDepartments = new List<project_department__c>();
 

    public class ProjectWrapper {
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public sfdc_project__c project;
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<TaskWrapper>tasks;
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<ContentDocumentLink> notes = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Project_Assignment__c> accounts = new List<project_assignment__c>();
        
       
    @TestVisible
        ProjectWrapper(sfdc_project__c project, List<TaskWrapper> tasks){
            this.project = project;
            this.tasks = tasks;
        }
        
    }

        Public class TaskWrapper{
        
            @AuraEnabled
            public Task task;
            @AuraEnabled
            public List<ContentDocumentLink> notes = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            
             @TestVisible
            TaskWrapper(Task task){
                this.task = task;
            }
        } 
        
        
            @AuraEnabled
        public static List<ProjectWrapper> getProjectWithTaskAndNotesByEpic(List<String> Departments ){     
            
                    system.debug('Department Selected: ' + Departments + ' szie: ' + Departments.size() );
    
           // if(projectIDs.size()>0 && projectIDs !=null)
           // 
           if (Departments.size() >0 && Departments != null){
                myLstProject =          [Select id,   sfdc_project_name__c,SFDC_Status_Description__c, SFDC_Project_Start_Date__c, SFDC_Project_Status__c, Project_Epic__r.name,
                                                  Priority__c,priority_Color__c, 
                                                  (select id, owner.name,subject, priority, status,description,activityDate ,   Task_Priority_Color__c from tasks) from sfdc_project__c 
                                         where project_department__c in:Departments and sfdc_project_status__c not in ('Completed','Cancelled')
                                         order by createddate desc
                                        ] ;
            }
            else
                 myLstProject =          [Select id,   sfdc_project_name__c,SFDC_Status_Description__c, SFDC_Project_Start_Date__c, SFDC_Project_Status__c, Project_Epic__r.name,
                                                  Priority__c,priority_Color__c, 
                                                  (select id, owner.name,subject, priority, status,description,activityDate ,   Task_Priority_Color__c  from tasks) from sfdc_project__c 
                                         where sfdc_project_status__c not in ('Completed','Cancelled')
                                         order by createddate desc
                                        ] ;
          
       
          system.debug ('# of projects returned:' + myLstProject.size()) ;
      
            //gather all LinkedEntityId for ContentDocumentLink Query
            List<id> linkedEntityIdList = new List<Id>();
            List<ContentDocumentLink>contentDocumentLinkList = new  List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            
            //create maps for future wrapper
            Map<ID, ProjectWrapper> idVsProjectWrapper = new Map<ID, ProjectWrapper> ();
            Map<ID,  TaskWrapper>  idVsTaskWrapper = new Map<ID,  TaskWrapper> ();        
    
            for(sfdc_project__c pj: myLstProject){
                linkedEntityIdList.add(pj.ID);
    
                List<TaskWrapper> taskWrapperList = new List<TaskWrapper>();
                
                for (Task tsk: pj.tasks){
                    linkedEntityIdList.add(tsk.ID);
                    
                    TaskWrapper tw = new TaskWrapper (tsk);
                    taskWrapperList.add(tw);
                    idVsTaskWrapper.put(tsk.ID, tw);
                }
                
                idVsProjectWrapper.put(pj.id, new ProjectWrapper(pj,taskWrapperList));
            }
             
                //Query ContentDocumentLink
                //
            if(linkedEntityIdList.size()>0){ 
                contentDocumentLinkList =[select contentdocumentlink.id, contentdocument.title, contentdocument.description ,linkedentity.name, linkedentity.id ,  contentdocument.CreatedDate ,contentdocument.CreatedBy.Name
                from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid in: linkedEntityIdList
                and sharetype='V' and contentdocument.filetype='SNOTE'];
            }   
                
                system.debug('# of Notes: ' + contentDocumentLinklist.size());
                
                for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: contentDocumentLinklist){
                    if(cdl.linkedEntityid.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getName() == 'sfdc_project__c')
                    {
                        system.debug('Project entity Name:' + cdl.linkedEntity.Name + ' Note Title: ' + cdl.ContentDocument.Title );
                        
                        idVsProjectWrapper.get(cdl.linkedentityid).notes.add(cdl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        idVsTaskWrapper.get(cdl.linkedentityid).notes.add(cdl);
                         system.debug('Task entity Name:' + cdl.linkedEntity.Name + ' Note Title: ' + cdl.ContentDocument.Title );
                    }
                }
            
            //query the project_assignment__c
            List<Project_Assignment__c> accts = [select id,  project__r.id,  project__r.sfdc_project_name__c, account__r.name, account__c from project_assignment__c where project__r.id in: linkedEntityIdList];
            
            for (Project_Assignment__c pa : accts){
              
                Id pid = pa.Project__c;
                
                system.debug('project id: ' + pID);
                   idVsProjectWrapper.get(pid).accounts.add(pa);
                system.debug('project account size: ' + idVsProjectWrapper.get(pid).accounts[0].Account__r.Name);
            } 
                
           
            return idVsProjectWrapper.values();
        }
        
        
        
      /*  @AuraEnabled
        public static List<Project_Epic__c> getProjectEpics()
        {
            return [select ID, Name from project_epic__c];
        }
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public static String  fetchUserProfile(){
            Profile p = [select id,Name from profile 
                      Where id =: userInfo.getProfileId()];
            system.debug('Profile Name:' + p.Name);
          return p.Name;
    
        }
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public static List<String> getDepartments(){
                   List<String> departments = new List<String>();
             /*   departments = [select  name  from  department__c  ]; 
            System.debug(departments.size());
            List<String> deptName = new List<String>();
            for(department__c d : departments){
                deptName.add(d.Name);
            }*/
            
            departments.add('Marketing');
            departments.add('CS/Marketing');        
                    departments.add('Channel Services');  
                    departments.add('Registry Services');  
            return  departments ;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: can u post cmp & controller code

Comment: I posted the code. pls let me know if you need the apex code as well. it is kind of long

Comment: Can you add code for `getProjectWithTaskAndNotesByEpic` apex method?

Comment: I just did. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Aura framework is "minified" (made smaller/faster at the expense of legibility). This error tells you that you did something that caused an error inside the Aura framework ("O" being the name of the obfuscated method name/property that was called). To figure out *what* that something is, however, we'd have to see the code, or you'd have to debug your code. These errors are unfortunately meaningless, and without seeing your own code, it'd be hard to know for sure what happened.

Comment: I am new to salesforce and web development. I use the developer console. not sure how to debug and see where it breaks. I edited my post and put the code there. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something attribute cache issue. Set your `lstProject` attribute as a null before assign new value. In your scenario, put below statement on handleChange method before calling `helper.getProjectAndTasks()` helper method.

```
component.set('v.lstProject',[]);
```

It will help to clear cache from attribute and will assign new value as per its assignment.